# Probability of a bp sequence in a DNA

Tags: probability, biology

Question:

> DNA is composed of two strands carrying a sequence of nucleotides: adenine (A), cytosine (C), guanine (G) and thymine (T). Nucleotides along the two strands pair (bond) with one another: A with T and G with C.
>
> A linear DNA fragment has $400000$ nucleotide pairs and we can assume that the share of A-T pairings equals G-C. If a probe is held at one end of the fragment and launched to scan for a particular sequence "GAATTC", how many successful scans do you expect after the probe reaches the other end?

My approach:

> Our scan sequence has $6$ nucleotides. $4^{6}$ different combinations of a six-nucleotide sequence are possible. Out of them, ONLY one sequence matches our probe. Therefore, for every $4^{6}\times6 = 24576$ nucleotides, we will get one successful scan. Thus, the expected number of successful scans = $\frac{400000}{24576} = 16.27 \approx 16$

However, the given answer is 97 and I appear to be undercounting by a factor of six. I did some more examples and I am always undercounting by the number of nucleotides in the recognition sequence. Will appreciate some insight into where I am going wrong.

The (proved) source of error:

> Someone asks in the comment below if not the multiplication with $6$ would have been an obvious place to look. Let's take a shorter example of a 2 nucleotide long recognition tag (say, AG).
>
> $4^{2} = 16$ 2-nucleotide seqs are possible. Out of which one matches!
>
> (AA)(GG)(TT)(CC)(**AG**)(AT)(AC)(GA)(GT)(GC)(CA)(CG)(CT)(TA)(TG)(TC)
>
> One match every $32$ $(4^{2} \times 2)$ nucleotides on average. [You might rearrange the order of the bracketed pairs but the probability of match remains same.]

Comment: Why did you multiply by $6$ when computing $4^6 \times 6$? If you're undercounting by a factor of $6$ and you multiplied by $6$ there then that's an obvious place to look, right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, clarified!

Comment: That's a match every $32$ nucleotides but that means it's a match every $16$ nucleotide *pairs*. And "pairs" would still imply multiplying by $2$ (which would be incorrect since the problem statement specifies the count of nucleotide pairs). So again, where does the $6$ come from?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - Is it because they are conceptually breaking the sequence up into pieces that are 6 bases long, thus missing any hits that start at positions that aren't a multiple of 6?

Comment: I say that there will be one match for every $4^{6}\times n$ nucleotide where $n$ is the number of nucleotides in the recognition sequence. Indeed you can say in my original case that there's a match every $4^{6}$ nucleotide sextuples.

Comment: @JonathanZ: oh, I see. AvadaMouse, that's incorrect. As Jonathan says, you aren't considering the possibility that there could be matches starting at positions that aren't a multiple of $6$. Actually there is one match every $4^6$ nucleotide pairs in expectation and you can verify this by doing numerical simulations (say with a sequence of length $3$ so that we won't get confused by the two possible meanings of "pair" with a sequence of length $2$). In your example there are actually two additional AG matches, one near the beginning at (AA)(GG) and one in the middle at (GA)(GT).

Comment: @AvadaMouse -  How many possible match sequences would you say there are in a sequence of $12$ nucleotides? Would you say $2$ or $7$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah - I missed out on those, indeed. An excellent perspective into where I was going wrong. How to reconceptualize this without using numerical simulations etc.?

Comment: The essential principle here is linearity of expectation, applied to every possible string of $6$ consecutive nucleotide pairs, starting at every possible location: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties

Comment: Ah - okay. Understood in my own way: There will be five more places to start (than the one we are already considering) and they will lead to differently bracketed sextuplets. Each of these six cases will have the same expectation and hence, my result has to be multiplied by six effectively canceling it out.